# Configuring options in ASP.NET Core Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, .net-core, asp.net-identity

Acording to the ASP.NET Core [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio), you create a a method to change the predefined options, called "Configure". However there is already a method in the class called configure.

```
  services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
    {
        // Password settings.
        options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
        options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
        options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
        options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
        options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
        options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 1;

        // Lockout settings.
        options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
        options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;
        options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;

        // User settings.
        options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters =
        "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@+";
        options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = false;
    });
```

You add this in the ConfigureServices method in the ConfigureServices class, but there is already a method called configure in the Configure service class.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    });
}
```

I am new to identity so I don't know which of them if either I can change. Right now I am getting this error regarding the naming:

"A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods"

Comment: You have to put methods in a class. You can call your method for configuring identity anything you like or it can be anonymous as it is in the code you posted

Comment: thank you, i realized that my class definition ended before the second configure method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all needed to be wrapped within the class definition

Comment: Note this requirement will be lifted in C# 9